# JQuery easing with queue function

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, easing

The following easing does not trigger. It does if queue:true is removed, but we need that bit too.

```
$(this).delay(delay).animate({left: '+' + bounceoffset + 'px', top:0, opacity:0.6}, {queue:true, duration:800}, 'elastic');
```

How is it done.

Answer (score -1):

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) doesn't say that specifying `queue: true` means `queue: 'fx'` which is the default queue.

It queues by default, so just drop the `queue: true`.

**EDIT** you're actually not using the correct format, which is

- either: `.animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete] )`
- or: `.animate( properties, options )`

In your case change `{queue:true, duration:800}` to `800`

RTFM.

**EDIT AGAIN**

You think you're using the first argument structure, but you're actually using the second one. JQuery sees an object as second parameter and thinks it's the second one.

I think the real problem is "elastic" is not really an easing function. So if 
JQuery ignores your last argument (thinking there's only two) your code works, but if you change `{queue:true, duration:800}` to `800`, JQuery assumes the first argument structure and fails because the easing you specified is undefined.

BTW. These are the easings defined in JQuery:

linear swing jswing def easeInQuad easeOutQuad easeInOutQuad easeInCubic easeOutCubic easeInOutCubic easeInQuart easeOutQuart easeInOutQuart easeInQuint easeOutQuint easeInOutQuint easeInSine easeOutSine easeInOutSine easeInExpo easeOutExpo easeInOutExpo easeInCirc easeOutCirc easeInOutCirc easeInElastic easeOutElastic easeInOutElastic easeInBack easeOutBack easeInOutBack easeInBounce easeOutBounce easeInOutBounce

Comment: No I need the queue:true in place as I said in my question

Comment: but it queues by default. see revised answer

Comment: It does not queue by default. The animate procedure does, but on firefox queue:true is still required in order to maintain the delay property

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could send me a link about that ff quirk? Anyway, see my revised answer.

Comment: No this is not quite correct. FIrstly elactic is an easing function that I created and that works perfectly except when combined with queue. This is true of any standard easing too. Secondly the reason queue true exists is because if it does not other portions of the code will not execute at exactly the same time. With this line in they always all act at the same time. I understand and thank you for your input but the objective here is not to assume this is a single line of unattached code, it is part of a much larger function.

Comment: The objective here is Q&A. As I explained, the way you use `.animate` in your question is wrong. The way you're using it JQuery takes the second argument as `options` and ignores the third parameter. Moreover, easing has nothing to do with queuing, because `.animate` first gets queued (unless `queue: false`) and only then executed with the chosen easing. If you look at the `speed` and `doAnimation` functions in jQuery you'll see what I mean. Good luck